# Run factor analysis on all variables or just those relevant to the factor we seek?

Tags: pca, dataset, factor-analysis, survey

I have a survey dataset. We asked numerous questions to get at one point: "how integrated are you in your community?" I want to run factor analysis to get a "community integration" factor.

Should I
(1) run FA on all the survey variables, and use the factor that looks like the "community integration" factor
OR
(2) run FA on just the "community integration" variables?

When I run option 1, there is a factor that is clearly the "community integration." So both options are feasible.

What are the implications of the two methods? What, theoretically or mathematically, is the difference between what I am capturing between the two approaches?

Comment: The mathematics of FA is indifferent to what the variables are or mean. In practice, an arbitrary mix of variables necessarily has implications for FA results, like anything else. I've seen people praising FA on a tight bundle of variables as "theoretically guided" and criticising the same thing as "circular argument", so choose your style and make your own choice.

Comment: I support Nick. FA is to uncover common latent traits which make the observed variables to correlate. This implies that the variables belong to the same content field, - but that is defined by you subjectively. Fortunately, there are diagnostic statistical indicators (such as KMO, Bartlett's sphericity test, pattern of residual correlations) which can aid to decide if to drop or to add variables from/to the analysis.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox and ttnphns. I try to conceive of what each option would capture. The first is something like a conditional factor maybe? It would define vectors that maximize variance and are orthogonal to other vectors. The second approach is just the vector that maximizes variance within the community variables. But in practical terms, I'm not sure what this suggests.